# how pagination work with sorting and search function

Tags: php, sorting, search, pagination

I am facing problem in pagination, searching and sorting function.
It function well if dint combine all with pagination. Once I sorting, the result did not change at every page which mean only will change in current page. For example, now i am at page 2 ,then i sorting,the result in page 2 have change due to what I sort by.However, the other page did not change , they all still by default.May I know what is going wrong. appreciate with your help.

```
<?php

include('db_connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product";

$r = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
$numrows = $r[0];

// number of rows to show per page
$rowsperpage = 2;
// find out total pages
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
// cast var as int
$currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
// default page num
$currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
// set current page to last page
$currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
// set current page to first page
$currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page 
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
$sOrder = "ORDER BY  product_id  ASC "; 

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $sort = $_POST["sort"];
        if($sort == "latest")
        {
            $sOrder = "ORDER BY date_update DESC "; 
        }
        else if ($sort == "lp")
        {
            $sOrder =  "ORDER BY  pro_price ASC"; 
        }
        else if ($sort == "hp")
        {
           $sOrder = "ORDER BY  pro_price DESC" ; 
        }

        else if ($sort == "AZ")
        {
             $sOrder =  "ORDER BY pro_name ASC";
        }

        else if ($sort == "ZA")
        {
             $sOrder =  "ORDER BY pro_name DESC"; 
        }

        else
        {
             $sOrder = " "; 
        }




if ( isset($_POST['sSearch']) && $_POST['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $search=mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] );
    $sWhere = " where pro_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(           $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' " ;
    }   
else{
    $sWhere = " ";
}


$currentpage = 1;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method = "POST">
 Sort by 
 <select name ="sort">
 <option value="all" checked>All</option>
 <option value="latest">Latest item</option>
<option value="lp">Lowest Price first</option>
<option value="hp">Highest Price first</option>
<option value="AZ">Alphabets A-Z</option>
<option value="ZA">Alphabets Z-A</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="sSearch" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php

// get the info from the db 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product $sWhere $sOrder LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql) ;
// while there are rows to be fetched...
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$pid = $list['product_id'];
?>
<div class='grid'>
<ul class="products">
<li class="cart_items">
<a href="proDetails.php?pid=<?php echo $pid ?>" class="product-image">
<img src="<?php echo "product/".$list['pro_photo']; ?>" style="max-height:140px;max-    width:140px" />
<?php echo "<br/>".htmlspecialchars($list['pro_name']); ?>
</a>
<?php echo "<br/> RM ".$list['pro_price']; ?>
&nbsp;
<form name = "btn" method = "POST" action="" >
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $pid ?>"/>
<input type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="30" value="1" size="30" />
</br>
<a href="" name="favourite" title="favourite"><img src="images/heart-add-icon.png"       name="favourite" onclick=""/></a>

<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add to Cart" class="add-to-cart" />

</form>
</li>
</ul>
```

```
<?php
    }

/******  build the pagination links ******/
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
// show << link to go back to page 1
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
// get previous page num
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
// show < link to go back to 1 page
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
// if it's a valid page number...
if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
  // if we're on current page...
  if ($x == $currentpage) {
     // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
     echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
  // if not current page...
  } else {
     // make it a link
     echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
  } // end else
} // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
// get next page
$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
// echo forward link for next page 
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
// echo forward link for lastpage
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First search and sort, then paginate. Otherwise it happens what happens to you. And there is no reason to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in your script, instead just use `<a href='?current...`. And don't forget to pass sort and search parameters per get parameters as well, otherwise they are lost (you're missing that, doing search and sort first, then pagination and forgetting about search and sort).

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you are retrieving ALL database records count. Therefore your `$numrows` and then `$totalpages` is always wrong and equal to rows retrieved for only sorting without any search.

To do real counting you should 1st build the search query.
EXAMPLE:

```
$querypart = ' from table where ...... order by ....';
$countQuery = 'select count(*) '.$querypart;
$query = 'select * '.$querypart;
```

Now if you execute the `$countQuery` you will get row count for given search and sort. and for executing `$query` you will get the rows.
of course you should add ad the end of `$query .= ' limit '.($page*$onPage).','.$onPage';` so you will retrieve only required page of rows instead of everyone.

Comment: Your meaning is replace $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product "; to
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product $sWhere $sOrder"; ,rite?? i hv try but it didn't work. I think may be is something wrong at if(isset($_POST["submit"])).

Comment: Also the pagination query should be not at the beggning but when you already know what to search for.
As for the links for next/prev page - you should add to them search query and sort order. As when you create them they just tells the page but without search restrains at all.